# Parallel PhoneGap development - app for iPhone and Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch

I am about to start developing an application using Sencha Touch and PhoneGap. It is supposed to be runnable on both iPhone and Android devices. I would like to get tips about how to set up my dev environment in the best way, to be able to constantly test on both platforms (device) with a common codebase on svn.

In the PoC that I have been doing until now, I have only the www-folder version controlled in svn, and checked out into my local Xcode project and then symlinked into my local Eclipse project (it didn't work to have symlink in xcode, it doesn't run on device then). This way all my webapp files are always updated in both platforms. However, now we will be more than one developer working on it, and we will need to have the whole projects version controlled too. My thought is to version control the Xcode-project in its full (with the www there), and the Eclipse without the www. Then locally each developer symlinks the www checkout from the xcode project to the eclipse project checkout. Makes sense? Anyone has any better idea or experience to share?

Comment: Have you considered a local git repository? xCode works very well with them.

Comment: git or svn in this case is not the big question for me, it is more about the whole setup of the project when developing both for iPhone and Android in parallel. But thanks anyway for your answer NJones :)

Answer (score 1):

I have also ran into this issue. Checking various solutions on the web I think there are three reasonable solutions.

1) Place www folder outside both projects and symlink them

2) Place www folder outside both projects and use build scripts to copy to the appropriate folder. In case of iOS use the build phases tab, in case of droid you can use an ant script.

3) Use git submodule (or svn external) feature.

See 1) and 3) in more details at http://www.senchatouchbits.com/8/organizing-files-within-phonegap-projects.html 
There are pros and cons for all solutions and your project's requirements (environment, etc).

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to do this is to use Adobes cloud build platform (PhoneGap Build) https://build.phonegap.com/

I usually develop as much as I can in just a text editor and debug with Chrome, when I go to dig in to specific device features I'll build from Github with PG Build and install the APK into the Android emulator for example.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969222/phonegap-3-and-ides)). From what I've seen on the demos that the PhoneGap devs have posted, they're using IDEs that are directory based rather than project based. Some are using the [Sublime Text editor](http://www.sublimetext.com/), while others are using the new open source editor [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), backed by some of the same PG people at Adobe.

Either one should allow your team to do their development in the /www folder instead of down in the /platforms directory. Currently I've got the platforms set up on different workstations for iOS, Android and WP7 (don't have a Windows 8 machine handy for WP8). I've been using Brackets for about a month -- it's not *quite* up to the same dev feature set as Visual Studio / Xcode, but it is showing a lot of promise. And it's a lot easier to manage the PG code than using Xcode / VS (or even Eclipse).