# PhoneGap 3 and IDEs

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm trying to grok the best practices workflow for PhoneGap 3, and was wondering how all this is supposed to tie together:

- For generic functionality, the code that is developed is in the top-level www folder.
- For phone-specific functionality, the code that is developed is under the platforms/platform/ directory.

BUT when using an IDE, the project files seem to be down in the /platforms directory (for example -- the .xcodeproj file for ios is in the /platforms/ios directory), and only includes the files under /platforms, not the top-level www directory.

My question / issue is this. We have a team that's used to working in IDEs like VS / Xcode. How do I set up a project that allows them to work on the top-level www files and emulate on the platform(s) they're focusing on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question appears to have come from the folks over at Adobe.

[Brackets](http://brackets.io/) is a relatively new open source IDE that is directory structure-focued, along the same vein as Smultron or TextWrangler, for those who are familiar with OS X editors. Hopefully this removes the temptation to go playing around in the /platforms directory instead of editing files in the top-level /www directory.

It has a plugin architecture, with support for Git / GitHub and PhoneGap Build. So far it looks pretty promising.